# How to recover passwords from Google Chrome login data file

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, passwords, password-recovery, sqlite

I have removed a standard user password on a windows machine with administrator user from console management; after removing the password of standard user when i open google chrome i don't see the password that saved before. all password was lost. again i set the last password for standard user but saved passwords in chrome are still missing.

also i tried to use third party app like chromepass or WebBrowserPassView but they show only username, and password field is blank.

Please tell me how i can recover the saved passwords?

Comment: Have you deleted users or did you only change passwords? It's not really clear what you mean.

Comment: See this tool https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html

Comment: @Ramhound user not removed. only the password was removed.

Comment: @zomega  user not removed. only the password was removed. the *Login Data* file is exists.

Comment: Simply go to Settings > Autofill > Password manager. You don't need a tool like WebBrowserPassView to view the passwords.

Comment: @zomega no password on Saved Passwords area. They are saved on *Login Data Database* File but not shown on this area. with third party tools like chromepass i can see them (just user names; passwords are encrypted and show them blank ) but in Chrome Saved Passwords area not visible. I know they are protected by Windows CryptProtectData function ;so how i can recover them in same machine and same user with old password?

Comment: Change the password back to your old password. Maybe Chrome uses your account password to decrypt the login data.

Comment: @zomega I have done this. Nothing happened.

Comment: I think the Login Data file is empty and there are no passwords stored inside. You can verify this. Download SQLite browser and run "SELECT password_value FROM logins;". I bet there is nothing stored inside. If the values are all the same or empty it means there are no passwords inside this file.